# CLIPS (not(vector)) and (not(registry (field))) has differents behaviours on LHS of rules

Tags: rules, clips

I've testing the proposal method for get commands from the book Adventures in
Rule‑Based Programming (chapter 3C).

The idea is to enter commands with facts, and evaluate if there is a unknown command.
I've experimented two suprising different behaviours:

```
(defrule read-command
(declare (salience -10))
(not (command))
=>
(bind $?com (readline))
)

(defrule bad-command
(declare (salience -10))
?com <- (command (action $?act))
=>
(println "Unknown command " ?act)
(rectract ?com)
)

;next, there would be right commands rules, with higher priority
```

With (run), the read-command rule fires, and if the user introduces a unkniown command, then the bad-command fires. This occurs in loop for ever. That's OK.

However, using a ordered vector for the command fact makes a distinct behaviour. When it's introduced a bad command the bad command rule fires, but the rule read-command doesn't. The program ends here, and there is not the desired loop.

What sense has this?

Answer (score 0):

After adding the missing deftemplate to your code fragment and fixing the typo for retract, the behavior of your code fragment does not match the behavior you're describing:

```
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate command
   (multislot action))
CLIPS> 
(defrule read-command
   (declare (salience -10))
   (not (command))
    =>
   (bind $?com (readline)))
CLIPS> 
(defrule bad-command
   (declare (salience -10))
   ?com <- (command (action $?act))
   =>
   (println "Unknown command " ?act)
   (retract ?com))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (agenda)
-10    read-command: *
For a total of 1 activation.
CLIPS> (run)
drink potion
CLIPS> (facts)
CLIPS>
```

The readline call in read-command will get a line of input from the user, but you're assigning to the variable $?com and nothing further is done with that variable so there's no way for the bad-command rule to be triggered.

Comment: Sorry Gary. I've written the code directly here and it was incomplete. Finally i've encountered the problem. I'm going to post my self answer,

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the problem of the code. I managed to solve the problem.

The right and complete code is:

kernel.clp:

```
;Read command
(defrule read-command
    (declare (salience -100))
    (not (command $?))
    =>
    (println)
    (print "prompt:> ")
    (bind $?com (readline))
    (bind $?comMulti (explode$ $?com))
    (assert (command ?comMulti))  
)

;Unknown command
(defrule unknown-command
    (declare (salience -100))
    ?idCom <- (command $?com)
    =>
    (println "Unknown command: " ?com)
    (retract ?idCom)
)

(defrule CLIPS-command
"Evals normal CLIPS commands from prompt, prefixed with CL
Example: prompt:> CL (facts)"
    ?idCom<-(command CL $?command)
    =>
    (retract ?idCom)
    (eval (implode$ ?command))
)
;command to return to CLIPS normal prompt
(defrule quit 
    ?c <- (command quit) 
    => 
    (retract ?c) 
    (halt)
)
```

problem-rules.clp:

```
;Command "new user"
(defrule get-username
    ?c <- (command new user)
=>
    (retract ?c)
    (print "Username: ")
    (bind ?resp (readline))
    (bind ?respMulti (explode$ ?resp))
    (if(> (length$ ?respMulti) 0)
    then 
        (assert (user name ?respMulti))
    )
)
```

The problem was that in the original read-command the first CE was

```
(not (command))
```

Without a wildcard for the command value. I think that the problem is that in rules with CEs matching ordered vectors facts, it's different (not (command)) than (not (command $?)).

On the other hand, there was not neither a (command) fact, but the rule read-command only was fired once. I guess the refraction is the cause of this. But i'm not sure...

Comment: If you're using deftemplate facts, then (command) will match any fact and (command (action)) will just match facts with no action values. If you're using ordered facts then (command $?) will match any fact and (command) will just match facts with no action values.